# nodejs no renderiza html

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

tengo el siguiente codigo de servidor

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const html = require('html');
require('./routes/index.routes')(app)

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + './app/public/')))

app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
   console.log(`Servidor corriendo en el puerto ${app.get('port')}`);
})
```

//aqui estan mis rutas

**index.routes.js**

```
const action = require('../controllers/index.controller')
module.exports = app =>{
 app.get('/', action.index)
}
```

**index.controller.js**

```
const ctrl = {}

ctrl.index = (req, res, next)=>{
 res.render('index.html')
}

module.exports = ctrl;
```

//El problemas es que no renderiza el index que tengo en la carpeta `app/public`
quiero aclarar que en la carpeta app estoy usando react
es la primera vez que incluyo react a un proyecto dentro de la carpeta app tengo todo lo que crea react al iniciar un proyecto con npm

**este es el error que me muerta el navegador**

> Error: Module "html" does not provide a view engine.

Comment: Para usar [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render), es necesario que uses un motor de plantillas [(*template engine*)](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html), de lo contrario no hay forma de enviar la vista renderizada desde `express`. Por otro lado, si usas `React` en el lado `frontend` ¿para qué necesitas enviar plantillas o vistas renderizadas desde el `backend`?. Me temo que te falta documentarte un poco sobre el tema. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te falta añadir el engine, para handlebars usa:

```js
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Aqui tienes un enlace a los tipos de engine disponibles: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html

y aquí la documentación de uso
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: pero yo quiero usar html, es necesario hacer lo que dices para poder renderizar el html?

Comment: creo que puedes usar tambien app.get('/',function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});